# when i don't update images it becomes blank and removed from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making Update form everything was good but now I am facing a problem and that is In update form if I update title but don't update image still when I submit image disappears But when i update image it is updated it is like when I don't update images it becomes blank  how to fix this problem?

Here is my code :

```
<?php
    include('includes/db.php');
    if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
      $edit_id=$_GET['edit'];
      $get_edit="select * from mobile_phone where mobile_id = '$edit_id'";
      $run_edit=mysqli_query($con,$get_edit);
      $row_edit=mysqli_fetch_array($run_edit);
       $update_id=$row_edit['mobile_id'];
      $m_title=$row_edit['mobile_name'];
      $brand_id=$row_edit['brand_id'];
      $m_image1=$row_edit['img1'];
      $m_image2=$row_edit['img2'];
      $m_image3=$row_edit['img3'];
      $m_price=$row_edit['price'];
      $m_desc=$row_edit['mobile_desc'];
      $m_key=$row_edit['product_keywords'];

    }
    // exact brand
    $get_brand="select * from brands where brand_id='$brand_id'";
    $run_brand=mysqli_query($con,$get_brand);
    $brand_row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brand);
    $brand_edit=$brand_row['brand_title'];
    ?>
```

here is html form part

```
 <tr>
    <td style="color:#fff"><b>Mobile Image 1</b></td>
   <td style="color:#fff"> <input type="file" name="Mimg1"><br><img src="mobile_images/<?php echo $m_image1; ?>" width="80" height="100">  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <td style="color:#fff"><b>Mobile Image 2</b></td>
    <td style="color:#fff"> <input type="file" name="Mimg2"><br><img src="mobile_images/<?php echo $m_image2; ?>" width="80" height="100">  </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="color:#fff"><b>Mobile Image 3</b></td>
    <td style="color:#fff"><input type="file" name="Mimg3" ><br><img src="mobile_images/<?php echo $m_image3; ?>" width="80" height="100"> </td>
</tr>

     <tr align="center">
    <td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" class="btn" name="update_mobile" value= "Update"></td>
</tr>
```

**//php part**

```
if(isset($_POST['update_mobile'])){
    //text data variables
$mobile_title=$_POST['Mname'];
$mobile_price=$_POST['Mprice'];
$mobile_brand=$_POST['Mbrand'];
$mobile_desc=$_POST['mdesc'];
$mobile_keywords = $_POST['key'];
//image names
$mobile_img1=$_FILES['Mimg1']['name'];
$mobile_img2=$_FILES['Mimg2']['name'];
$mobile_img3=$_FILES['Mimg3']['name'];

//Image temporary names
$temp_name1=$_FILES['Mimg1']['tmp_name'];
$temp_name2=$_FILES['Mimg2']['tmp_name'];
$temp_name3=$_FILES['Mimg3']['tmp_name'];

if($mobile_title=='' OR $mobile_brand=='' OR $mobile_price=='' OR $mobile_desc=='' ){
    echo"<script>alert('please fill all the fields!')</script>";
    exit();
}
else{

    //uploading image to its folder

move_uploaded_file($temp_name1, "mobile_images/$mobile_img1");
move_uploaded_file($temp_name2, "mobile_images/$mobile_img2");
move_uploaded_file($temp_name3, "mobile_images/$mobile_img3");
$update_mobile= "update mobile_phone set mobile_name='$mobile_title',brand_id='$mobile_brand',date=NOW(),price='$mobile_price',img1='$mobile_img1',img2='$mobile_img2',img3='$mobile_img3',mobile_desc='$mobile_desc',product_keywords='$mobile_keywords' where mobile_id='$update_id'";
 $run_update= mysqli_query($con,$update_mobile);
if($run_update){

    echo "<script>alert('mobile updated successfully')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('index.php?view','_self')</script>";
}
}
}

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean, it becomes blank? Can you explain?

Comment: the previous image is removed from database

Comment: It is blank because you are always updating the image field in the database regardless of whether or not the $_FILES array has data. You need to dynamically build you update statement based on what the user has submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if some image was selected from each input. You are updating even the user not select some image:

This is the code you can try:

```
if(isset($_POST['update_mobile'])){
    //text data variables
$mobile_title=$_POST['Mname'];
$mobile_price=$_POST['Mprice'];
$mobile_brand=$_POST['Mbrand'];
$mobile_desc=$_POST['mdesc'];
$mobile_keywords = $_POST['key'];


if($mobile_title=='' OR $mobile_brand=='' OR $mobile_price=='' OR $mobile_desc=='' ){
    echo"<script>alert('please fill all the fields!')</script>";
    exit();
}
else{


// Declare the columns that always will be updated
$queryUpdateFields = "mobile_name='$mobile_title',brand_id='$mobile_brand',date=NOW(),price='$mobile_price',mobile_desc='$mobile_desc',product_keywords='$mobile_keywords'"

// check if the images exist
if ($_FILES['Mimg1']['size'] != 0) {
    $temp_name1=$_FILES['Mimg1']['tmp_name'];
    $mobile_img1=$_FILES['Mimg1']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name1, "mobile_images/$mobile_img1");
    $queryUpdateFields .= ", img1='$mobile_img1'"; // image exists, so, concatenate to update
}

if ($_FILES['Mimg2']['size'] != 0) {
    $temp_name2=$_FILES['Mimg2']['tmp_name'];
    $mobile_img2=$_FILES['Mimg2']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name2, "mobile_images/$mobile_img2");
    $queryUpdateFields .= ", img2='$mobile_img2'";
}
if ($_FILES['Mimg3']['size'] != 0) {
    $temp_name3=$_FILES['Mimg3']['tmp_name'];
    $mobile_img3=$_FILES['Mimg3']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name3, "mobile_images/$mobile_img3");
    $queryUpdateFields .= ", img3='$mobile_img3'";
}


$update_mobile= "update mobile_phone set " . $queryUpdateFields . " where mobile_id='$update_id'";
 $run_update= mysqli_query($con,$update_mobile);
if($run_update){

    echo "<script>alert('mobile updated successfully')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('index.php?view','_self')</script>";
}
}
}
```

I didn't test. You can get the logic and apply if it doesn't work. Let me know what happened.

Comment: the logic I want to apply is first check if image exists if exists than admin has the choice to keep or update.

Comment: I've updated the code to better check if image exists.